# MPMoviePlayerController can't read file in document path

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, document

I recorded a video and copied it to the path

```
NSURL *videoPath =[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUsersDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0],@"/output.mov"]];
```

Then use MPMoviePlayer to play it:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMovieController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoPath];
```

This does not work. The video can't get loaded. The file path is

```
"/var/mobile/Applications/12341235-12354125-123412-41/Documents/output.mov"
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some weird reason, `MPMoviePlayerController` doesn't seem to like certain `NSURL`s even though they are deemed as valid objects.

The "secret" is to get the file path as `NSString` and then use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:URLStringPath]` to create the URLs your are using to create the `MPMoviePlayerController` instance.

Comment: Thanks. This works. However, I still can't use requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption: to get thumbnails. It says that :domain avfoundationerrordomain code=-11800. Do you know why?

Comment: You help me to save a few hours of headache.

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to set / for your file path use like this

```
NSURL *videoPath =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUsersDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0],@"output.mov"]];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just figure out that I should use [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath] instead of videoPath alone. However, I still can't get thumbnails with this player. It says "The operation could not be compete." Do you know why?

Comment: instead of nsurl urlwithstring use nsurl fileurlwithpath as your file path get operation porcess